# Is Bourbon chometz gomur or tarovot chometz?

Tags: kashrut-kosher, passover, liquor-beer

On first look bourbon - legally >50% corn, usually 70%+ - is a mix of corn and chometz whiskey, so should be a chometz mix, not chometz gomur.

(Assuming that wheat and barley whiskey & beer are chometz gomur.  A different question can debate this point.)

The Mishna Berura 442:1 says that even if you do not get rid of (sell) chometz mix you can eat it after Passover.

```
משנה ברורה סימן תמב ס"ק א
ואם עבר ולא ביערם עד לאחר הפסח מותרין באכילה
```

The cRc & OU have issues and say that Bourbon is not normal chometz mix based on Mishnah Berurah 442:27, as referenced in [Q&A 3 in linked PDF](https://consumer.crckosher.org/wp-content/uploads/2023/01/AKO-Whisky-Alert-with-QA-Sep-2010.pdf).

MB there is referring to whiskey added to cheese, and if you do not get rid of (sell) it then it is only allowed if great loss, and you need to destroy the benefit of the chometz that is in it.

```
משנה ברורה סימן תמב ס"ק כז
יש להתיר במקום הפסד מרובה בהנאה ע"י השלכת הנאת המעמיד לים המלח
```

The Aruk HaShulchan says in 442:20 that a potato (vodka?) mixed with a bit of grain whiskey is chometz gomur.

```
    ערוך השולחן אורח חיים סימן תמב סעיף כ
ואפילו יי"ש שעושים מתפוחי אדמה וגם חלק מדגן יש בזה מהדגן כזית בכדי אכילת פרס וחייבין כרת לרוב הפוסקים ועוד דעיקר המעמיד הוא המאל"ץ של שעורים שהוא חמץ גמור
```

Why would the grain be the maymad?  Can you not make moonshine without grain?  Would a corn instead of potato base make a difference?

Then in 442:21 The AS says chometz used as mamad or flavor is ossur.

```
ואף על גב דדבר המעמיד ומילתא דעביד לטעמא אינו אלא דרבנן מ"מ הוי כמו הדבר בעין ואפילו בדיעבד אסור [ח"י סקט"ז] ואפילו השהה אותה עד לאחר הפסח אסור
```

Why is this different to any other chometz mix as in 442:1.  The case of chometz mix given in the gemarra is a bread, salt and whey mix.  Does the bread not mamid or give flavor?

Is there something in the brewing of bourbon that would make it different?  Why do I not say its a simple mix of corn and wheat, like rice krispies etc?  Is the grain whiskey a maamad?  How does it work?

Comment: Rav Chaim David HaLevi has a long teshuvah about homeopathic medicines made with alcohol. I can't find it now because I'm away from my library, but there he discusses opinions that whiskey is not food at all, which he says cannot be relied on alone but can be a factor combined with others) and whether the alcohol is probably made out of corn or other grains. You might find that teshuva helpful and might find some more sources there.

Comment: Incidentally, there are 100% corn bourbons on the market, though none are as yet certified KfP kitnyot as far as I know

Comment: The question is based on grain whiskey being a food and chometz gomur - why is standard bourbon treated as chometz gomur.  One of many nafka mena being if you do not sell chometz gomur can you sell your burbon.  All bourbons I get have grains in it but if I ever got a 100% corn there is no reason to consider it chometz gomur.  100% corn sold in shops are unlikely to be chometz free as need new stills etc. And they are allowed to add without putting on label

Comment: Whether whiskey is chamutz gamur should be part of the analysis of whether mainstream bourbons are chametz gamur, which is the question ITT. Regardless, the teshuvah I mentioned also talks about corn versus grain whiskey IIR. He may talk about how we handle mixtures and sfeikot. It's a start.

Comment: Bourbon is a mix of corn and grain alcohol.  If grain alcohol is not chometz then for sure bourbon is not.  The question only starts if it is.  I state in the question that I am asking according to the shita that it is.  The debate about whether grain alcohol is chometz is a totally different question which I am not asking.  Most kashrut organisations OU, OK, Star K, cRc hold it is.  The Aruk hahshulchan 442 says it is.  I am asking a different question.